# Error 1004: SaveAs Method Failed, accessMode:=xlShared

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with a macro.

```
Sub ActivePartage()

Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFile As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormat As Integer
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

strTestString = Left(Destwb.Name, (InStrRev(Destwb.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
TempFile = "H:\DQM\Tableau de Bord DQM\" & strTestString

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFile & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, AccessMode:=xlShared
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I tried to figure it out why there is an error (filenamen format...etc)
I know it's working without `AccessMode:=xlShared`, but I need to save it as shared mode.
I am using Excel 2016, my code has been inspired from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.multiuserediting):

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Maybe not cause of error but you declared FileFormat variable and use FileFormatNum (I corrected this before running code). Advise not to have a variable with same name as a property or argument. Use Option Explicit in module header and misspellings like this will be revealed. Workbook is saved but when I open it, get "Project is unviewable" in the VBE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be caused because to save a files as shared you first needs to have exclusive access to it.

try opening it in exclusive then save as shared.

```
With Destwb
    .ExclusiveAccess
    .SaveAs TempFile & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, AccessMode:=xlShared
```